# Self Join Entity Object update as NULL

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have created one Entity Framework with Self Join Relationship. When I update self joined Object as Some Value it is getting updated Succesfully but when I want to Update this object as NULL. It throw exception. Here is my code:-

```
 var data = (from p in objContext.Categories where p.Id == model.Id select p).FirstOrDefault();

               if (model.Id != model.ParentId)
               {
                   data.Description = model.Description;
                   data.Name = model.Name;
                   data.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
                   data.Slug = model.Slug;
                   data.Status = model.Status;
                   data.CreatedDates = DateTime.Now;
                   data.Id = model.Id;

                   if (model.ParentId == 0)
                   {
                      data.Category1 = null;
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       data.Category1 = (from p in objContext.Categories where p.Id == model.ParentId select p).SingleOrDefault();
                   }

                   objContext.SaveChanges();
                   return UserFriendlyMessage.CategoryUpdate;
               }
               else
               {
                   return UserFriendlyMessage.CategoryInvalidParent;
               }
```

Below is my Entity Class:-

```
public partial class Category
    {
        public Category()
        {
            this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
            this.Categories = new HashSet<Category>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime CreatedDates { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public System.DateTime LastChangeDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Slug { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category1 { get; set; }
    }
```

Thanks,
Parveen Kumar

Comment: Where do you set the null ? 
If you want to remove child, you should use the Remove() method.

Comment: data.Category1 = new Category();

Comment: Copy here the exception message.

Comment: Please look at Updated Code, where I want to set it as NULL. data.Category1 = null;

Comment: As I said, if you want to remove the child, you need to use the Remove method.
objContext.Categories.Remove(data.Category1);
Only then, it will be null.

Comment: I tried that but Remove will completely delete it entries. But i want to Remove its Foreign Key reference only

Comment: Ok, so you should set data.Category1.ParentId to null (if its nullable).

Comment: Getting Error after I set it as 0,data.Category1.Id = 0;.The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified

Comment: You should set Category1.ParentId to null. If you set 0, it is looking for parent category with id 0 (which doesn't exists, and thats why you're getting exception)

Comment: integer value cannot be set as NULL and data.Category1.Id is Integer type

Comment: I'm talking about ParentId, not Id.

Comment: ParentId is also integer Type

Comment: In this case, every Category must have parent category. You should change it to nullable.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understood from the comments,

 
what you're trying to do, is to keep the sub category in the database, but remove the refernce to it's parent category.

The solution for this, is to set the subcomment.ParentId to null.

```
           if (model.Id != model.ParentId)
           {
               data.Description = model.Description;
               data.Name = model.Name;
               data.LastChangeDate = DateTime.Now;
               data.Slug = model.Slug;
               data.Status = model.Status;
               data.CreatedDates = DateTime.Now;
               data.Id = model.Id;

               if (model.ParentId == 0)
               {
                 **data.Category1.ParentId = null;**
               }
               else
               {
                   data.Category1 = (from p in objContext.Categories where p.Id == model.ParentId select p).SingleOrDefault();
               }

               objContext.SaveChanges();
               return UserFriendlyMessage.CategoryUpdate;
           }
```

Comment: I don't have any ParentId in Entity class. it is Id. and after setting
data.Category1.Id=0. it giving error.
The property 'Id' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Comment: So what is your Foreign Key ?

Comment: Category1 is Object. Its relationship is Self Join So It behave as a foregin key

Comment: If you don't have ParentId, where did it came from: 'model.ParentId'  (in the if statement) ?

Comment: It is my Model, I have created one property with this name. In Entity class there is no ParentId exist.

Comment: So whats connecting between the parent and the child ?

Comment: See my Updated Code in Question. I have mentioned there Entity Class.